# Paint Draw Image from another Thread?

Tags: c#, image, panel, draw

I read that you can increase the drawing speed/time by drawing with the paint event, and with that you can also draw unscaled.

So i would very much like to try it on my panel.

The problem is though, the image is recieved in another Thread then the GUI, and i don´t know how to give it to the paint event.

I really don´t want to invoke and stuff (as that is incredibly slow, at least when i have used it).

The code will look, something like this.

```
protected override void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, Image u)
{

        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(u, Point.Empty);

}
```

Though there i tried using override to add to add an image in the field, ald i wanted to make it static, so i could call it from a Thread. Sadly i t didn´t work.

But well, i tried.

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

     //   e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(u, Point.Empty);

}
```

There is the "working" one, except i can´t get the image to it.

I tried making an image variable, then save the image in that variable, and paint it.
but paint does never see the image in it, it can´t access the Image, guess cause it´s written from another thread.

```
//initialize
private Image Im;

////////

my Thread
 Im = Image.FromStream(....);
////////////7

         void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        { 
                if(Im !=null)
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Im, Point.Empty);          
        }
```

This is how i tried, and failed.

Comment: try this e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Image.FromFile(@"C:\..\..\yourimage.jpg"), new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200)); - the rect is optional you can use point and with your dimensions.

Comment: The image is from a Stream, and a new one comes in all the time.

Comment: cant you use backgroundworker?

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing? Is it the cross thread exception? If so you have to use the BeginInvoke methods to paint on UI thread

Comment: Don´t know how to do that.

I am not getting an error, it´s just not working, as i can´t give paint the image, or at least i don´t know how to do it.

Comment: Shouldnt the Point be pointing to a x,y location in screen?

Comment: Also try BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { [paint] })); for painting on main thread

Comment: > The image is from a Stream, and a new one comes in all the time

Hey, seems you have not synchronized the Image. So, it could be write by one Thread the same time the paint method gets called!?
Seems an issue.

Comment: Not sure what you meant there, but if i use Panel.BackgroundImage = Imagefromstream(...), it works perfectly.

But from my understanding, this should be faster. that´s why i want to use it, or atleast try it.